# Save Button Issue

Tags: acumatica

I have a Custom screen called Collection Options with 3 tabs (screenshot 1). The first tab is the main tab linked with the CollectionOptions DAC and graph. The other 2 tabs used 2 different DACs. When clicking the Save button on the Preferences and Access Rights Users tabs to save values and/or changes, the save button does not work, but when I am on the Collection Options tabs the changes on the Preferences and Access Rights Users tabs tend to save, What could be the issue?

**Screenshot 1:**

[image]

**Screenshot 2: Collection Options tab Properties**

[image]

**Screenshot 3: Preferences tab properties**
[image]

**Screenshot 4: Access Rights Users tab properties**

[image]

**COllection Option Graph View codes**

```
    public class CollectionOptionsGraph : PXGraph<CollectionOptionsGraph>
    {
       
        public PXSelect<CollectionOptions> View;
        public PXSave<CollectionOptions> Save;
        public PXCancel<CollectionOptions> Cancel;

        public PXSelect<ProofOfDeliveryPreferences> ViewPreference;

        public PXSave<ProofOfDeliveryPreferences> SavePreference;
        public PXCancel<ProofOfDeliveryPreferences> CancelPreference;

        public PXSave<PODUsers> SavePODUsers;
        public PXCancel<PODUsers> CancelPODUsers;

        public PXSelect<PODUsers> PODUsers;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need one `PXSave` and `PXCancel` on your graph.
I don't know which one is your primary view in the datasource, but if it is `CollectionOptions`, then you need to use `PXSave<CollectionOptions>` and `PXCancel<CollectionOptions>`